# Lag function returning 0s

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I've been trying to create a gdp growth rate column in my dataset but there seems to be an error with my lag function, in a way that it only returns 0s.

Can you spot if there's anything wrong with my code?

```
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(real_gdp_pc = rgdpo / emp) %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  mutate(growthrate_realgdppc = (real_gdp_pc - lag(real_gdp_pc)) / lag(real_gdp_pc)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Here is the dataset I'm working with (including the growthrate_realgdppc with the 0s I'm referring to): https://drive.google.com/file/d/12UmdYKH4tSM5ICOD2F82VDXzqcbWfM7P/view?usp=sharing

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is working.  Try:

```
tail(df2)
```

and see if you have values in that line.